# Why is $\operatorname{Cov}\left[v^TX,v_1^TX\right] = v^T\operatorname{Var}\left(X\right)v_1$?

Tags: linear-algebra, probability, statistics, covariance, multivariate-statistical-analysis

I came across the following result in one of the proofs exposed in my multivariate analysis course and I haven't been able to prove it :

Let $X=(X_1,\dots,X_p)$ be a random vector in $\mathbb{R}^p$. Then

\begin{equation} \label{1}
\operatorname{Cov}\left(v^TX,v_1^TX\right) = v^T\Sigma v_1,
\end{equation}

where

- $\Sigma := \operatorname{Var}(X) = \left[\operatorname{Cov}(X_i,X_j)\right]_{i,j=1,\dots,p}$
- $v \in \mathcal{S}^{p-1}$, where $\mathcal{S}^{p-1}$ is the unit sphere
- $v_1 := \underset{v \in \mathcal{S}^{p-1}}{\arg\max} \operatorname{Var}(v^TX)$

#### Note:

I'm not sure if the definitions of $v$ and $v_1$ should play somewhat of a role in the proof of the result (meaning that the statement might be proven for any vector $v$ and $v_1$) but it is how they are defined in the context of the course.

Comment: If $X$ and $Y$ are random vectors, then $\mathbf{Cov}(X, Y) = E((X - \mu_X) (Y - \mu_Y)^\intercal).$ Now do the algebra.

Comment: Or, you can use that $\mathbf{Cov}$ is bilinear...

Comment: Thank you for your response @WilliamM. I should have mentionned that I already tried to apply the definition of the covariance operator:

$
\operatorname{Cov}\left(v^TX,v_1^TX\right) = 
E\left(\left(v^TX - \mu_{v^TX}\right)\left(v_1^TX - \mu_{v_1^TX}\right)^T\right) = E\left(\left(v^TX - E\left[v^TX\right]\right)\left(v_1^TX - E\left[v_1^TX\right]\right)^T\right)
$. 
But I do not understand how to continue since there's doesn't seem to be any cancellation nor properties to exploit when distributing the main product.

Comment: Furthermore, how can the bilinearity of $\operatorname{Cov}$ be used since $v$ and $v_1$ are vectors and not scalars ?

Comment: $v^\intercal X = v_1 X_1 + \ldots + v_d X_d.$

Comment: Use $[(x^⊤ u)(x^⊤ v)] = [u^⊤ (xx^⊤) v] = u^⊤ [xx^⊤]v$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the hints provided to me in the comments, Here's the proof I came up with:

Let $\boldsymbol{v}=\begin{pmatrix} v_1, \dots, v_p \end{pmatrix}$ and $\boldsymbol{v_1}=\begin{pmatrix} v_{11}, \dots, v_{1p} \end{pmatrix}$. Using the covariance's bilinearity, we have

\begin{align}
&\operatorname{Cov}\left(v^TX,v_1^TX\right) = 
\operatorname{Cov}\left(v_1X_1 +\dots+ v_pX_p, v_{11}X_1 +\dots+ v_{1p}X_p\right)
\\\\
&= v_1\operatorname{Cov}\left(X_1,v_{11}X_1 +\dots+ v_{1p}X_p\right)
+ \dots + v_p\operatorname{Cov}\left(X_p,v_{11}X_1 +\dots+ v_{1p}X_p\right)
\\\\
&= v_1\left[\operatorname{Cov}\left(X_1,X_1\right)v_{11} + \dots + \operatorname{Cov}\left(X_1,X_p\right)v_{11}\right] + \dots + v_p\left[\operatorname{Cov}\left(X_p,X_1\right)v_{11} + \dots + \operatorname{Cov}\left(X_p,X_p\right)v_{11}\right]
\\\\
&= v_1\begin{bmatrix}\operatorname{Cov}\left(X_1,X_1\right) & \dots & \operatorname{Cov}\left(X_1,X_p\right)\end{bmatrix}\boldsymbol{v_1}
+ \dots + v_p\begin{bmatrix}\operatorname{Cov}\left(X_p,X_1\right) & \dots & \operatorname{Cov}\left(X_p,X_p\right)\end{bmatrix}\boldsymbol{v_1}
\\\\
&= \boldsymbol{v}^T \begin{bmatrix}\operatorname{Cov}\left(X_1,X_1\right) & \dots & \operatorname{Cov}\left(X_1,X_p\right) \\
\vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
\operatorname{Cov}\left(X_p,X_1\right) & \dots & \operatorname{Cov}\left(X_p,X_p\right)
\end{bmatrix} \boldsymbol{v_1}
\\\\
&= \boldsymbol{v}^T\Sigma \boldsymbol{v_1}
\end{align}